# Did Wolfram|Alpha mess up $\int 1 - \frac{1}{1-e^{-x}} \mathrm{d}x$ or did I?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, wolfram-alpha

I want to calculate $$\int 1 - \frac{1}{1-e^{-x}} \mathrm{d}x$$

Provided that $x>0$. Substituting $u=1-e^{-x}$, we get:

$$\int \frac{1 - \frac{1}{u}}{1-u} \mathrm{d}u = -\int \frac{1 - \frac{1}{u}}{u-1} \mathrm{d}u = -\int \frac{1}{u} \mathrm{d}u=-\ln(u)+C=-\ln(1-e^{-x})+C$$

Differentiating the result gives the integrand, so I think it correct.

However [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1-1%2F%281-e%5E%28-x%29%29) gives the result $x-\ln(1-e^x)$, which is imaginary for $x\geq0$ and doesn't the integrand when differentiated. What is going on?

Comment: I see you just removed the complex-integration tag yet, I would say, that's a major source of the discrepancy!

Comment: @MarkMcClure But I approved an edit adding it, which did not reflect the post correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\displaystyle I = \int \left(1-\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}\right)dx = -\int\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}dx\;,$$

Now let $$(1-e^{-x}) = t\;,$$ Then $\displaystyle (+e^{-x})dx = dt$

So $$\displaystyle I = -\int\frac{1}{t}dt = \ln\left|1-e^{-x}\right| = -\left[\ln\left(\frac{e^{x}-1}{e^x}\right)\right] = -\ln\left|e^x-1\right|+\ln(e^x)$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I = -\ln\left|e^x-1\right|+x+\mathcal{C}$$

Comment: Oh Sorry.. Yes Bungo

Comment: Perhaps one of the most often made mistakes in calculus: $$\int \frac{1}{x} dx = \ln |t|$$, not $\ln t$. The whole question was just due do this.

Comment: This is a plausible story but not what Alpha appears to have done.  There is some process involving complex contour integrals by which Alpha really does seem to want imaginary numbers in the constant of integration.

Comment: +1 For showing how to obtain the WA result, with the exception of the absolute value bars. In fact, those absolute bars (contrary to the assertion made by @wythagoras) are not quite correct here. This is actually where key source of the discrepancy arises, since the symbolic functionality in Mathematica (and, therfore, WA) makes the implicit assumption that all variables are *complex*. In that context, the absolute value bars are simply incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

> However Wolfram|Alpha gives the result x−ln(1−ex), which is imaginary for x≥0 and doesn't the integrand when differentiated. What is going on?

Your answer equals $-\log(e^x - 1) + \log(e^x)$ which is Wolfram's form up to some possible weirdness about adding $\log(-1)$ to the constant of integration.

The weirdness disappears when differentiating, and also has to do with where the basepoint $a$ is taken to be if you think of the integral as $\int_a^x (\cdots)$.  Switching from positive to negative $a$ is like computing this as a complex contour integral and making half a loop around the singularity at $0$, so picking up half a $2 \pi i$.

Given the above, there must be some consistent algorithm that Alpha follows, and it is working correctly in that the derivative of its answer is the integrand.

It could be that Alpha writes Log(x) in the output but uses Log|x| internally in its calculations.  If so then there is no problem with any imaginary terms.  But Alpha's output, when following the link in the question, includes this below the answer:

> Series expansion of the integral at $x=0$
>   $$(-\log(x)-i \pi)+x/2-x^2/24+x^4/2880+O(x^6)$$

and another $i \pi$ in the "alternate form for $x>0$".

The explanation in terms of basepoints and contour integrals seems closer to what is happening at the server.

Comment: No. The answer lies in the often forgotten fact that $\int \frac1t =\ln | t|$, not $\ln t$, which Wolfram didn't give correctly either.

Comment: I was editing the answer as you commented.  Log |x| may be the issue or not.

Comment: Note the "half of $2 \pi i$" appearing twice in Wolfram's output using the link you provided.  It does seem like some complex contour integration is involved.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the integrand into one fraction and do $$\int\frac{-e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}dx=-\ln|1-e^{-x}|+c$$ since this is of the form $$\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx$$

Comment: That is essentialy what I did expepted that I didn't see the trick.